# How can I use linq to search inside a list of objects

Tags: c#, linq

I am new in linq and I want to use it in a list without use a `foreach`. How can I return a list from a list of objects `List<House>` where house ha swimming pool.

```
Class Houses
{
  Int Id,
  bool HasSwimmingPool
...
}
```

Comment: You don't even need LINQ: `List<House> houses = houses.FindAll(h => h.HasSwimmingPool)`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fh1w7y8z(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @TimSchmelter, he knows that, he could do a ForEach, he obviously wants to use LINQ.

Comment: Yes I know but as T McKeown mentioned I want to start using Linq

Comment: ForEach is not List.FindAll.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need is `Where` method, which filters collection based of given predicate:

```
var results = source.Where(x => x.HasSwimmingPool).ToList();
```

Additional `ToList()` call makes the results `List<House>` instead of `IEnumerable<House>`.

You can achieve the same using syntax-based query:

```
var results = (from h in source
               where h.HasSwimmingPool
               select h).ToList();
```

Comment: It's worth noting that LINQ is not even required in this case. He can use [`List.FindAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fh1w7y8z(v=vs.110).aspx): `List<House> houses = allHouses.FindAll(h => h.HasSwimmingPool)`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter The advantage of LINQ is that instead of learning how to perform common operations on every single possible type of data source, you learn one single API for writing queries that can be used independent of the type of the underlying data source.  This can be powerful in the ability to write code that allows the underlying data source to be changed, but it's also useful in simply not needing to memorize, as a programmer, the API for querying a whole bunch of different types of data sources.  There's value in that.

Answer (score 1):

That is simple:

```
var yourCollection = new List<Houses>();
var housesThatHasASwimmingPool = yourCollection.Where(s => s.HasSwimmingPool);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
 var swimmngHomes = listOfHouses.
     Where( h => h.HasSwimmingPool == true);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Houses> housesWithPools = oldHouses.Where(x => x.HasSwimmingPool== true);
```